# Dealing with Large XML files in dataset (out of memory)

Tags: vb.net, dataset, out-of-memory

I'm trying to read a 1GB XML file with almost 1 million records through a URL and store `<file>` in a dataset and save them to a database, but after 10 minutes, the application will crash and throw an `Out of Memory Exception`.

The XML looks like this:

```xml
<ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/files.index.xsd">
  <files.index Generated="20200220011050">
    <file path="export/freexml.int/INT/1399.xml" Product_ID="1399" Updated="20200122151223" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="1" Prod_ID="C4872A" Catid="377" On_Market="1" Model_Name="80" Product_View="333140" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/1399_4084669833.jpg" HighPicSize="2734733" HighPicWidth="4200" HighPicHeight="2772" Date_Added="20051027000000" Limited="No"></file>
    <file path="export/freexml.int/INT/1400.xml" Product_ID="1400" Updated="20200122151313" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="1" Prod_ID="C4874A" Catid="377" On_Market="1" Model_Name="80" Product_View="283127" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/1400_6603855084.jpg" HighPicSize="2734913" HighPicWidth="4200" HighPicHeight="2952" Date_Added="20051027000000" Limited="No"></file>
  </files.index>
</ICECAT-interface>
```

**Sub Main():**

```vb
Class Module1
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim url As String = "http://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml/EN/daily.index.xml"
        ProcessXMLFeedURL(url)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Function:**

```vb
Public Shared Function ProcessXMLFeedURL(MyURL As String) As Boolean
    Dim OK As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim rssReq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(MyURL)
        Dim username As String = ""
        Dim password As String = ""
        Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password))
        rssReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)
        '//Get the WebResponse
        Dim rep As WebResponse = rssReq.GetResponse()
        '//Read the Response in a XMLTextReader
        Dim xtr As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(rep.GetResponseStream())
        '// Set up the connection to the SQL server
        Dim MyConnectionString As String = "Data Source=...."
        Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
        Dim MyServer As Server = New Server(New ServerConnection(Connection))
        Dim db As Database = New Database(MyServer, "xxxxxx")
        db.Create()
        '//Create a new DataSet
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        ds.ReadXml(xtr)
        '// Parse tables
        Dim Mytable As Table
        Dim MyTableName As String = ds.Tables(1).TableName
        If Not HaveTable(MyConnectionString, MyTableName) Then
                '// Create the table
                Try
                    Mytable = New Table(db, MyTableName)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Dim ii As Integer = 0
                End Try
                '// create the columns
                Dim Mycolumn As Column = New Column()
            For Each dc As DataColumn In ds.Tables(1).Columns
                Mycolumn = New Column(Mytable, dc.ColumnName)
                Mycolumn.DataType = getdatatype(dc.DataType.ToString)
                Mytable.Columns.Add(Mycolumn)
            Next
            Mytable.Create()
            Dim PrimaryKeys() As DataColumn = ds.Tables(1).PrimaryKey
            Dim PrimaryKey As DataColumn
                For Each PrimaryKey In PrimaryKeys
                    Dim Myindex As Index = New Index(Mytable, PrimaryKey.ColumnName)
                    Myindex.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey
                    Myindex.IndexedColumns.Add(New IndexedColumn(Myindex, PrimaryKey.ColumnName))
                    Mytable.Indexes.Add(Myindex)
                Next
            End If
            Using MyConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
                MyConnection.Open()
                Using bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(MyConnection)
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[databasename].[dbo].[" + MyTableName + "]"
                Try
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables(1))
                Catch ex As Exception
                        Dim iw As Integer = 0
                    End Try
                End Using
                MyConnection.Close()
            End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex '// Do errorhanddling here
    End Try
    Return OK
End Function
```

Comment: A 1GB xml file which is made up of text will take considerably more space on disk than it does when loaded into memory, especially if you serialize to CLR objects, but you don't see the value in doing that. Plus, you have at least 2GB limit for your object so you *absolutely* will not run out of memory this way.

Comment: What is the `Table` class you are dealing with? When do you actually run out of memory, i.e. where in the code?